# O que não dá pra fazer com f-string que dá pra fazer quando se utiliza .format?

Tags: python

Olá eu gostaria de saber em que casos eu preciso utilizar o método format ao invés de f-string porque com f-string não é possível fazer. Por exemplo acho que não é possível com f-string escrever um número formatado:

```
'fps: {:.1f}'.format(55.3578) => fps: 55.3
```

Comment: *fstring* permite formatar as casas decimais assim como no `format`. no seu caso bastaria `f'fps: {55.3578:.1f}'`, assumindo que está em python 3.6+. Tanto quanto sei, acho que não há nada que você possa fazer com `format` que não possa fazer com *fstring*

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade, dá sim.

```
f"fps {55.3578:.1f}"
```

As fstrings aceitam qualquer expressão Python válida,e você ainda pode colocar o ":" para especificar a formatação, usando todas as possibilidades que existem para o  `format`.